# Python - Pandas - how to extract content of specific row without header column

Tags: python

I would like to get the content of specific row without header column , I'm going to use df.iloc[row number] , but it didn't give me an expected result ?
my code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],
    'last_name': ['Smith', 'Doe', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'age': [34, 29, 37, 52, 26, 32]},
    )
df.head()
df_temp = df.loc[2]
```

The result i get is:

```
first_name      Marry
last_name     Jackson
age                37
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

I expected it could give me a list , sth like below:
['Marry', 'Jackson','37']
Any idea to do this, could you please advise for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are many functions in `pandas` that could help you do this. `to_String()` or `values` are a few among them.
So if you do something like

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],
    'last_name': ['Smith', 'Doe', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'age': [34, 29, 37, 52, 26, 32]},
    )
df.head()
df_temp = df.loc[2].to_String()
print(df_temp)
```

you will get an output like this for your given code:

```
first_name      Marry
last_name     Jackson
age                37
```

however in your case because you want a list you can just call `values` and get it as you want. Here's your updated code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'Layla'],
    'last_name': ['Smith', 'Doe', 'Jackson', 'Smith', 'Brown', 'Martinez'],
    'age': [34, 29, 37, 52, 26, 32]},
    )
df.head()
df_temp = df.loc[2].values
print(df_temp)
```

which will give you the output you probably want as

```
['Marry' 'Jackson' 37]
```